# Strange behaviour of handling handling dot character by ngx.re.match openresty module

Tags: regex, lua, openresty

I have a problem with understanding escaping "special" characters in Lua.
I read that dot can be escaped by putting % before character. The strange thing happens when I am trying to use **openresty** and lua nginx module, that matches regular expressions `ngx.re.match`

`local path = /offers/xyz:req:test0030-10-title:co/test`

`local regex = ^/offers/([0-9a-zA-Z_:%-%.]+)/test$"`

`local matches = ngx.re.match(path, regex) => returns nil`

I don't understand why this works correctly when I move `%.` before `%-`.

Can anyone help me understand that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NGINX uses a PCRE regex library](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) while Lua uses very limited Lua patterns.

In your case, `%-%` creates a range between `%` and `%` (i.e. `%-%` matches a `%`) and that means the `[0-9a-zA-Z_:%-%.]+` pattern does not match a hyphen at all.

You need

```
^/offers/([0-9a-zA-Z_:.-]+)/test$
                      ^^
```

At the end of the character class, `-` denotes a literal `-` char. You do not need to escape a `.` inside a character class, never.

You may also [test your PCRE patterns at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/6Sfwyx/2).